# MySQL: Could not acquire management access. OS error when starting server

Tags: mysql

I have this problem where I can't run a server in MySQL because it says i'm not running windows. I have been using Windows 11 and I encountered this issue.
I tested the connection and it works.

I have tried lots of things from other posts on Stack Overflow and none seemed to work. I've also reconfigured MySQL server.
[image: Wrong OS error]

These are the settings

[image: Settings]

Finally after I close the previous error, this is the last one that prompts.
[image: Last error]

Comment: https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html - I doubt if version 5.5 is supported if 5.7 isn't,  why 5.5 anyway?

Comment: It was the default. I've tried using 8.0 and restarting everything but didn't solve it either

Comment: Right-click MySQL Workbench and select Open as Administrator.

Comment: I'd try to run workbench in compatibility mode: right click on the icon and open properties. There you should find a tab "Compatibility" hopefully.

Comment: Thanks, but none worked